# Passing data through Intents

Tags: android, android-intent

I always get a `java.lang.NullPointerException` when retrieve the data from my `MainActivity` to my second `Activity`.

This from my `MainActivity`:

```
Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,ScanActivity.class);
i.putExtra("isConnected", String.valueOf(isConnected));
i.putExtra("serverIP", serverIP);
startActivity(i);
```

And here's where I get the `NullPointerException`:

```
Intent extras = getIntent();
public String isConnected = extras.getStringExtra("isConnected");
public String serverIP = extras.getStringExtra("serverIP");
```

Is my code wrong or is there something else that causes it to be `null`?

Comment: Are you doing it outside of the `onCreate()` method of the second `Activity`?

Comment: yes. is that what causes it?

Comment: It Likely does.

Comment: Where is your second piece of code specifically? In what method, and when does that method get called?

Comment: Are you very sure that your isConnected and serverIP got data inside?

Comment: Onik was right. i put the getIntent outside the onCreate method on my second activity. (silly me)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot get `Intent` until `SecondActivity` is instantiated. It's the reason for `NPE`. Move the code inside of the `SecondActivity`'s `onCreate()` method body.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.your_layout);

    Intent extras = getIntent();
    String isConnected = extras.getStringExtra("isConnected");
    String serverIP = extras.getStringExtra("serverIP");
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You should use this on your secondary activity

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
if(bundle != null){
 String serverIp = bundle.getString("serverIP);
}
```

you should condition it first to avoid null pointer, Hope this works.

Comment: THis isn't the answer.  You can use the convenience methods to avoid getting the bundle, they do the null checking for you.

Comment: I see , my bad. I'm still a newbie.

Comment: No big deal, we all give a wrong answer sometimes.  You code works just fine, but so would his if he did it in the right spot.

Comment: Yeah , he should put it inside the oncreate